# Change of Variables Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am searching for a proof of the following theorem:

> **THEOREM**
>
> Suppose $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is a  random vector with joint density function $f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ and $g$ is a smooth transformation on the domain of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Then the joint density of $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)= g(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is
> $$ f_{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n }(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(g^{-1}(y_1, \ldots, y_n)) \cdot |\det \mathcal{J}(g^{-1}(y_1, \ldots , y_n))|.$$

Maybe someone can give me some hints or references to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straightforward using the change of variable formula, and the characterization
of the law of a variable $X$ by the application

$$
f \ge 0 \to E[f(X)]
$$

Comment: I am familiar with the change of variable formula in the following version:

$$ \int_{\Omega} f( g(x)) | \det g'(x)| \, \text{d} \lambda(x) = \int_{g(\Omega)} f(y) \, \text{d}\lambda(y)$$

Comment: then, what does it give with $\displaystyle\int f_{X}(x_1\dots x_n)F(x_1\dots x_n) dx_1\dots dx_n$, for any given $F$?

Comment: @user144697 you **need** to integrate with some function $F$. otherwise this has little interest. Start with $EF(Y) = \int f_X(x)F(g(x)) dx$ and you should be fine.

Comment: Please look at my "answer". I hope it is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user144697 it seems good to me. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

[These](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~jyhhaur/teaching/advancedcalculusII2013spring/Lax.pdf) pages will help.

[Here](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/105/handouts/ChangeVariableThm.pdf) there is the theorem for $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \mathbb{E} F(Y)= \mathbb{E} F(g(X)) = \int  F(g(x)) f_X(x) \, \text{d} x = [y=g(x), x=g^{-1}(y)]=\\
=\int F(y) f_X(g^{-1}(y)) | \det \mathcal{J}g^{-1}(y)| \, \text{d}y$$
$\Longrightarrow f_Y(y) =f_X(g^{-1}(y)) $

Comment: It seems like it gets the job done.